# How to install opticspy python?

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to install opticspy, but I'm getting this error;
"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users...\Temp\pip-build-oslof619\matplotlib"

Thanks for your help,
Ramsey

Answer (score 1):

You use command `$ pip install opticspy` ? http://opticspy.org/

For Windows - installer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opticspy

Comment: yes, and it downloaded opticspy, then began installing it, but stopped with the mentioned error. Keynote; I'm installing it on a surfacepro 2; 64bit, and I wonder if that has a slightly different windows 10 version, that means it won't install with the normal command?

Comment: I tried using the same command on a regular 64bit PC running windows 7, it installed fine, so I think it must be something to do with the Surface Pro 2

Comment: Tried to install only matplotlib?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: it gave an error at the end of the installation, I think it must be something to do with the fact that I'm trying to run it on Surace pro 2 :S the error i got trying to install matplotlib is; Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\...\matplotlib

Comment: OK, so I've upgraded pip, and installed matlibplot, but now I've got this error; Command "python setuppy egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\...\pip-build-0jfpo123\unwrap\